# i can't receive any email if enabled email forwarding

Tags: email, smtp, postfix-mta, dovecot

if I enabled email forwarding, I can't receive any email but when I disabled email forwarding. Then webmail working fine. Anyone, please look into email logs? I don't see any sending and receiving problems. when email forwarding disabled on cyberpanel.

This problem only appear after enabling email forwarding.

```
Mar 29 07:14:01 blastoff postfix/bounce[2809]: 3DC8B3410DD: sender non-delivery notification: C9CED3410DE
Mar 29 07:14:01 blastoff postfix/qmgr[1082]: 3DC8B3410DD: removed
Mar 29 07:14:01 blastoff postfix/smtp[2934]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:4023:c03::1b]:25: Network is unreachable
Mar 29 07:14:02 blastoff postfix/smtp[2934]: C9CED3410DE: to=<riadloud@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.137.26]:25, delay=0.86, delays=0.01/0.07/0.36/0.42, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK  1617002042 i21si16857578otj.220 - gsmtp)
Mar 29 07:14:02 blastoff postfix/qmgr[1082]: C9CED3410DE: removed
Mar 29 07:14:32 blastoff dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<riad@blastoff.us>, method=PLAIN, rip=::1, lip=::1, mpid=2967, TLS, session=<QfcVoqe+6pUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
Mar 29 07:14:32 blastoff dovecot: imap(riad@blastoff.us)<2967><QfcVoqe+6pUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>: Logged out in=89 out=1045 deleted=0 expunged=0 trashed=0 hdr_count=0 hdr_bytes=0 body_count=0 body_bytes=0
Mar 29 07:16:32 blastoff dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<riad@blastoff.us>, method=PLAIN, rip=::1, lip=::1, mpid=3043, TLS, session=<b41Aqae+7JUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
Mar 29 07:16:32 blastoff dovecot: imap(riad@blastoff.us)<3043><b41Aqae+7JUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>: Logged out in=89 out=1045 deleted=0 expunged=0 trashed=0 hdr_count=0 hdr_bytes=0 body_count=0 body_bytes=0
Mar 29 07:17:18 blastoff postfix/anvil[2916]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:209.85.217.53) at Mar 29 07:13:56
Mar 29 07:17:18 blastoff postfix/anvil[2916]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:209.85.217.53) at Mar 29 07:13:56
Mar 29 07:17:18 blastoff postfix/anvil[2916]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Mar 29 07:13:56
Mar 29 07:17:24 blastoff dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<riad@blastoff.us>, method=PLAIN, rip=::1, lip=::1, mpid=3087, TLS, session=<3BlfrKe+7pUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
Mar 29 07:17:24 blastoff dovecot: imap(riad@blastoff.us)<3087><3BlfrKe+7pUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>: Logged out in=240 out=1300 deleted=0 expunged=0 trashed=0 hdr_count=0 hdr_bytes=0 body_count=0 body_bytes=0
Mar 29 07:18:17 blastoff spamd[3146]: logger: removing stderr method
Mar 29 07:18:17 blastoff spamd[3148]: config: no rules were found! Do you need to run 'sa-update'?
Mar 29 07:18:18 blastoff spamd[3146]: child process [3148] exited or timed out without signaling production of a PID file: exit 255 at /usr/sbin/spamd line 3034.
Mar 29 07:18:19 blastoff spamd[3150]: logger: removing stderr method
Mar 29 07:18:19 blastoff spamd[3152]: config: no rules were found! Do you need to run 'sa-update'?
Mar 29 07:18:20 blastoff spamd[3150]: child process [3152] exited or timed out without signaling production of a PID file: exit 255 at /usr/sbin/spamd line 3034.
Mar 29 07:18:21 blastoff spamd[3156]: logger: removing stderr method
Mar 29 07:18:21 blastoff spamd[3158]: config: no rules were found! Do you need to run 'sa-update'?
Mar 29 07:18:22 blastoff spamd[3156]: child process [3158] exited or timed out without signaling production of a PID file: exit 255 at /usr/sbin/spamd line 3034.
Mar 29 07:18:23 blastoff spamd[3159]: logger: removing stderr method
Mar 29 07:18:23 blastoff spamd[3161]: config: no rules were found! Do you need to run 'sa-update'?
Mar 29 07:18:24 blastoff spamd[3159]: child process [3161] exited or timed out without signaling production of a PID file: exit 255 at /usr/sbin/spamd line 3034.
Mar 29 07:18:24 blastoff spamd[3162]: logger: removing stderr method
Mar 29 07:18:24 blastoff spamd[3164]: config: no rules were found! Do you need to run 'sa-update'?
Mar 29 07:18:25 blastoff spamd[3162]: child process [3164] exited or timed out without signaling production of a PID file: exit 255 at /usr/sbin/spamd line 3034.
Mar 29 07:18:32 blastoff dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<riad@blastoff.us>, method=PLAIN, rip=::1, lip=::1, mpid=3176, TLS, session=<qhxjsKe+8JUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
Mar 29 07:18:32 blastoff dovecot: imap(riad@blastoff.us)<3176><qhxjsKe+8JUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>: Logged out in=89 out=1053 deleted=0 expunged=0 trashed=0 hdr_count=0 hdr_bytes=0 body_count=0 body_bytes=0
Mar 29 07:19:15 blastoff postfix/smtpd[3197]: connect from mail-vs1-f45.google.com[209.85.217.45]
Mar 29 07:19:15 blastoff postfix/smtpd[3197]: 9043434088F: client=mail-vs1-f45.google.com[209.85.217.45]
Mar 29 07:19:15 blastoff postfix/smtpd[3197]: warning: connect to /var/log/policyServerSocket: No such file or directory
Mar 29 07:19:16 blastoff postfix/smtpd[3197]: warning: connect to /var/log/policyServerSocket: No such file or directory
Mar 29 07:19:16 blastoff postfix/smtpd[3197]: warning: problem talking to server /var/log/policyServerSocket: No such file or directory
Mar 29 07:19:16 blastoff postfix/cleanup[3201]: 9043434088F: hold: header Received: from mail-vs1-f45.google.com (mail-vs1-f45.google.com [209.85.217.45])??by mail.blastoff.us (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 9043434088F??for <riad@blastoff.us>; Mon, 29 Mar 2021 07:19:15 +0000 (UTC from mail-vs1-f45.google.com[209.85.217.45]; from=<riadloud@gmail.com> to=<riad@blastoff.us> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-vs1-f45.google.com>
Mar 29 07:19:16 blastoff postfix/cleanup[3201]: 9043434088F: message-id=<CACGWsS=QumtoJMTYX49XNFv7Kbk_-+xhJ4TrZdFezAytvToTow@mail.gmail.com>
Mar 29 07:19:16 blastoff opendkim[920]: 9043434088F: s=20161025 d=gmail.com SSL
Mar 29 07:19:16 blastoff postfix/smtpd[3197]: disconnect from mail-vs1-f45.google.com[209.85.217.45] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=7
Mar 29 07:19:17 blastoff postfix/qmgr[1082]: 07B043410DD: from=<riadloud@gmail.com>, size=2541, nrcpt=2 (queue active)
Mar 29 07:19:19 blastoff postfix/pipe[3212]: 07B043410DD: to=<riad@blastoff.us>, relay=spamassassin, delay=3.7, delays=1.6/0.01/0/2, dsn=5.3.0, status=bounced (command line usage error. Command output: lda: Fatal: Unknown argument: unix Usage: dovecot-lda [-c <config file>] [-d <username>] [-p <path>]                    [-m <mailbox>] [-e] [-k] [-f <envelope sender>]                    [-a <original envelope recipient>]                    [-r <final envelope recipient>]  )
Mar 29 07:19:19 blastoff postfix/pipe[3213]: 07B043410DD: to=<riadshout@gmail.com>, orig_to=<riad@blastoff.us>, relay=spamassassin, delay=3.7, delays=1.6/0.02/0/2, dsn=5.3.0, status=bounced (command line usage error. Command output: lda: Fatal: Unknown argument: unix Usage: dovecot-lda [-c <config file>] [-d <username>] [-p <path>]                    [-m <mailbox>] [-e] [-k] [-f <envelope sender>]                    [-a <original envelope recipient>]                    [-r <final envelope recipient>]  )
Mar 29 07:19:19 blastoff postfix/cleanup[3201]: 3AEDA3410DE: message-id=<20210329071919.3AEDA3410DE@mail.blastoff.us>
Mar 29 07:19:19 blastoff postfix/bounce[3217]: 07B043410DD: sender non-delivery notification: 3AEDA3410DE
Mar 29 07:19:19 blastoff postfix/qmgr[1082]: 3AEDA3410DE: from=<>, size=6095, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 29 07:19:19 blastoff postfix/qmgr[1082]: 07B043410DD: removed
Mar 29 07:19:19 blastoff postfix/smtp[3220]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:4023:c03::1a]:25: Network is unreachable
Mar 29 07:19:19 blastoff postfix/smtp[3220]: 3AEDA3410DE: to=<riadloud@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.137.26]:25, delay=0.67, delays=0/0.02/0.29/0.35, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK  1617002359 g9si17981450plj.221 - gsmtp)
Mar 29 07:19:19 blastoff postfix/qmgr[1082]: 3AEDA3410DE: removed
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many configuration issues here.
The one that is causing the reject is:

```
command line usage error. Command output: lda: Fatal: Unknown argument: unix Usage: dovecot-lda [-c <config file>] [-d <username>] [-p <path>]
```

But there are also spamassassin issues (no rules found) and other milter issues (/var/log/policyServerSocket missing).

It doesn’t look like a forwarding issue but a general misconfiguration issue.

It is quite difficult to provide a precise advice here, you should review the whole configuration with someone familiar with this stuff.